# Have two rewrite cond for removing .php and google friendly URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I Would like to remove .php from all of my web pages **and** also have a Google friendly url in my blog pages. for example http:// example.com/about.php must be http:// example.com/about and http:// example.com/blog.php?id=1&title=2 must be http:// example.com/blog/1/2

I use **.htaccess** and edit that like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /blog.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

But when I browse, i just face to HTTP 500, Internal Server Error.
What's wrong with me?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that when you use the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` variable with the `-f`, apache will try to "fuzzy guess" what the requested filename *is*. In your case, you have a php file called `/blog.php`. And when you request `/blog/1/2`, the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` and `-f` will go through the path to look for a valid existing file, so:

- `/blog/1/2.php` = not exists, -f fails
- `/blog/1.php/2` = not exists, -f fails
- `/blog.php/1/2` = exists as PATHINFO, -f success

But...

You append a `.php` **to the end of the URI**, resulting in a URI that looks like:

```
/blog/1/2.php
```

Now, the rules loop, and the same thing happens:

- `/blog/1/2.php.php` = not exists, -f fails
- `/blog/1.php/2.php` = not exists, -f fails
- `/blog.php/1/2.php` = exists as PATHINFO, -f success

and you append `.php` again:

```
/blog/1/2.php.php
```

until you reach the internal redirect limit and the server returns a 500 error.

To fix this, either swap the order of the rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /blog.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Or add a more specific `-f` check:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /blog.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```